# PHP/SQL search form: which collation for making it insensitive to white space, order, and punctuation?

Tags: php, sql, collation

I have a search form that pulls data from a SQL database designed in phpmyadmin via PHP. Right now, the colums have utf8_general_ci collations, but I want the search to be not only case-insensitive and accent-insensitive (as it already is), but also insensitive to punctuation, order and white space.
For example, if my search box looks for an author, and my database entry is "Edgar Allan Poe", I want it to find this result even if someone fills the search box with:
- "Poe Edgar Allan"
- "Edgar Poe"
- "Edgar, Allan Poe"
(or another variation)

What collation do I need to choose to achieve this? Can I just change the collation in phpmyadmin, or do I need to add something to my code?

Comment: Why don't you just use PHP's uasort() instead?

Comment: @AbhiBeckert First of all sorting is different from filtering. Second of all Because database filtering and sorting works on hundreds of thousands of records while PHP filtering and sorting is limited to the memory limit somewhere in the thousands of records.

Comment: @user3504783 please mention the SQL backend you are using (MySQL, PostgreSQL, MSSQL ?).

Comment: @MihaiStancu in my experience PHP is faster than MySQL at sorting, if the data fits in RAM. If it doesn't fit in RAM, sure you can't use it. But the person asking this question didn't say they have a large data set.

Comment: @Mihai Stancu I'm not really sure what that means (I'm only a beginner), but I think MySQL would be the answer.

Comment: @user3504783 what I'm saying is why don't you just fetch all the results without any sorting, and then sort them in PHP code. Using the uasort function. It's going to be much easier than Sphinx Search or Apache Solr as Mihai Stancu suggested, I've implemented those and it's not easy.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert -- SQL servers are always **much**, **much** faster at sorting and filtering than PHP custom sorting/filtering functions. One reason for this is the fact that the SQL servers have been designed for precisely this task!

Comment: @AbhiBeckert -- and even if they were close to being equally fast, bringing data that you don't need into PHP (such as rows that the SQL server would have filtered out) is a pointless waste of RAM.

Comment: Almost any decent database is expected to grow over a couple of hundred rows. If you're a beginner and are using a shared hosting you have a fixed limit on your PHP memory_limit as imposed by the hosting company -- @AbhiBeckert' solution will not scale once the number of rows in your DB grows. And even if you're a professional programmer with your own dedicated server to play with, setting the memory_limit higher for something like this will make your application consume much more memory for no good reason.

Comment: @MihaiStancu Solr requires at least a few hundred megabytes of RAM to run and any hosting company that lets you install Solr should also let you set your PHP memory limit pretty high, say 100MB. You can easily sort a million rows with PHP's memory limit set to 100MB, and it will take two or three milliseconds. Yes, if you have gigabytes of data you need Solr, but most databases do not grow that size. Also, you can always switch to Solr when it does get that big. I'm not saying Solr is a bad idea, it's great. But you should only use it if your database is actually big.

Comment: Ultimately the proper approach is to use PHP to sort the array, test how fast it is and how much RAM it uses, and if it's too slow or uses too much RAM you should switch to Solr or Lucene.

Comment: @user3504783 how many rows are in your table? 100? 10000? Millions?

Comment: @AbhiBeckert a hosting company would either give you "shared" access to a separate physical search server or give you a VPS/DDS to install both your application and any other software you like, including a search server. If you have a VPS/DDS then you can indeed set your own memory limits to what ever you want.

Comment: I don't think PHP level processing can ever be considered the "proper" approach. Which is why I'll update my answer with a way to create your own content indexing structures in MySQL.

Comment: AbhiBeckert's proposal has a linear growing cost (as the database/table gets bigger, the cost gets bigger). That is because it processes all of the rows in the database every time someone attempts a search query.

Comment: The "custom built search index" I've added to my answer has a "constant" cost because it processes only one data item at a time (when inserting it) and another constant cost (when attempting a search query).

Answer (score 2):

### It's not that simple:

What you want to do is cannot be accomplished via collation alone. Collations only influence how the binary representation of text is interpreted, if a particular byte or group of bytes are read an uppercase or a lowercase or accented etc..

It cant reorder words for you, this has to be done either somewhere in the application code or by using more advanced text search indexing.

### FULL TEXT indexing:

Most relational database management systems (RDBMS) like MySQL have a [FULL TEXT indexing feature](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html).

In MySQL FULL TEXT indexing doesn't help in making "fuzzy" searches it just creates a search index which allows the searches to be performed on the entire length of the text (not limited to 1024 characters like normal indexes are) and make the searches run faster.

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
    `id` UNSIGNED INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` VARCHAR(255),
    `short_description` VARCHAR(1023),
    `description` TEXT,

    PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
    FULLTEXT (`title`, `body`)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

More on MySQL FULLTEXT indexing **[here](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/5688/how-to-mysql-fulltext-searching/p1)**.

Some of them implement even more complex and configurable [FULL TEXT indexing features](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/textsearch-indexes.html) such as GiST and GIN.

In PostgreSQL I'm not very experienced but as far as I know GiST and GIN have some special functionality such as allowing you to use [soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex), [metaphone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphone) and custom functions to make "fuzzy" searches and it also works on some of the positional information between word (I think...).

### Search servers:

To achieve what you want to achieve you most likely will need either a custom handwritten SQL query to cover word reordering or a search server such as [Sphinx Search](http://sphinxsearch.com/) or [Apache Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/).

There is a MySQL module that connects to a Sphinx Server -- it makes the Sphinx Server less complex to utilize because you'll be managing it as if it was just another table in your MySQL server the only difference being the fact that you specify `Engine=Sphinx` when creating the table.

Search servers allow you to configure priorities based on where the information was found (in the title vs in the description) and they search for variations based on word positions and things like that. If the search words are found in a text then the farther apart they are from each other, the lower the quality of the match (the results are sorted by relevance).

Search servers have logical grammar like Google such as specifying that a word should be excluded from the search or that two words need to be found exactly next to each other.

Search servers allow you to configure indexes that use `stem` words -- based on the language of the text, the words are read and analyzed for their base/root which allows searching for `programmer` and receiving results such as `programming` even though `'programmer' != 'programming'`.

They also allow you to configure multiple indexes with different priorities, the highest priority would be the original text index, another would be the stemmed index, a third could be a synonym index the fourth and fifth could be soundex or metaphone indexes.

You can configure aliases, word replacements, common error replacements etc..

### Custom built indexing structures:

`data_table` is the table containing what ever original content you would want to search through.

```
CREATE TABLE `data_table` (
    `id` UNSIGNED INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` VARCHAR(255),
    `short_description` VARCHAR(1023),
    `description` TEXT,

    PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
    FULLTEXT (`title`, `body`)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE `search_dictionary` (
    `id` UNSIGNED INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `word` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY (`word`)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE `search_index` (
    `id` UNSIGNED INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `item_id` UNSIGNED INT NOT NULL,
    `word_id` UNSIGNED INT NOT NULL,
    `weight` UNSIGNED INT NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY(`item_id`, `word_id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Whenever you insert a new record into the data table you also process the following:

```
/* We need to differentiate how important it is
 * if we find a word in the title of an item versus
 * finding it in the description.
 */
define('SEARCH_WORD_TITLE_WEIGHT', 100);
define('SEARCH_WORD_SHORT_DESCRIPTION_WEIGHT', 10);
define('SEARCH_WORD_DESCRIPTION_WEIGHT', 1);

/* assuming we have a new item such as the one below */
$dataTableItem = array(
    'id' => NULL,
    'title' => $title
    'short_description' => $short_description
    'description' => $description,
);

/* we insert the new item and receive its new ID as a return value */
$dataTableItemId = insert_new_item($dataTableItem);
insert_search_index($dataTableItemId, $title, SEARCH_WORD_TITLE_WEIGHT);
insert_search_index($dataTableItemId, $short_description, SEARCH_WORD_SHORT_DESCRIPTION_WEIGHT);
insert_search_index($dataTableItemId, $description, SEARCH_WORD_DESCRIPTION_WEIGHT);
```

An example of how you could implement `insert_search_index`:

```
/* We need words to be a minimum number of characters
 * otherwise they will be ignored by the search index.
 */
define('SEARCH_WORD_MIN_LENGTH', 3);

function insert_search_index ($itemId, $text, $weight = 1) {
    /* replace every character which isn't a-z, A-Z, 0-9 or space with space */
    $text = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]*/', ' ', $text);

    /* explode the text into an array of words */
    $text = explode(' ', $text);

    foreach ($text as $word) {
        if (strlen($word) >= SEARCH_WORD_MIN_LENGTH) {

            /* counting the number of occurences */
            if (isset($words[$word])) {
                $words[$word]++
            } else {
                $words[$word] = 1
            }
        } 
    }

    /* Insert all new words int dictionary
     * we ensure we only insert new words by
     * having `search_dictionary`.`word` unique
     * and using INSERT IGNORE
     */
    $insert_dictionary_query = '
        INSERT IGNORE INTO `search_dictionary`
                (`word`)
            VALUES '
                .'('.implode('), (', array_keys($words)).')
    ';
    $pdo->exec($insert_dictionary_query);

    /* Select all `word_id`s for the words we
     * just added and insert them into the
     * search_index along with the $weight
     */
    foreach ($words as $word => $repetition) {
        $insert_index_query = '
            INSERT IGNOR INTO `search_index`
                    (`item_id`, `word_id`, `weight`)
                VALUES
                    '.$itemId.', (
                        SELECT `id`
                            FROM `search_dictionary`
                            WHERE `word` = '.$word.'
                    ), '.($weight * $repetition).'
        ';
        $pdo->exec($insert_index_query);

        if ($pdo->lastInsertId() === null) {
            $update_index_query = '
                UPDATE `search_index`
                    SET `weight` = `weight` + '.($weight * $repetition).'
                    WHERE `item_id` = '.$itemId.'
                    AND   `word_id` = (
                        SELECT `id`
                            FROM `search_dictionary`
                            WHERE `word` = '."'".$word."'".'
                    );
            ';
        }
    }
}
```

Finally we need to query the search index to search for a particular (set of) words:

```
/* Assuming we have a search query in $_GET['q'] */
$_GET['q'] = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]*/', ' ', $_GET['q']);
$_GET['q'] = explode(' ', $_GET['q']);
$_GET['q'] = array_unique($_GET['q']);

$select_search_index_query = '
    SELECT        `search_index`.`item_id`,
                  SUM(`search_index`.`weight`) AS `total_weight`
        FROM      `search_index`
        LEFT JOIN `search_dictionary`
            ON    `search_index`.`word_id` = `search_dictionary`.`id`
        WHERE     `search_dictionary`.`word` IN('."'".implode("','", $_GET['q'])."'".')
        GROUP BY  `search_index`.`item_id`
        ORDER BY  `total_weight`
';
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It will be on a shared hosting. I expect the number of categories to stay roughly he same, but the number of entries will grow to a large one.

Comment: This all sounds very complicated to me, so I have two questions: 1: If I wanted to forget about the reordering problem, is there an easy fix for ignoring punctuation? 2: What's the easiest way to include Sphinx? I looked at the manual, but it's so complex that I have no idea what to do with it. I only just started learning PHP and SQL, and I'm only using phpmyadmin to create my table. I really don't need much out of it either, just a solution to the ordering problem I mentioned above, and maybe a check for alternative spelling (like "theater" vs. "theatre"). Is there an easy tutorial?

Comment: If you're on a shared hosting you will not be able to install things yourself, not even modules of software so Sphinx and/or Solr could be provided by the host if not, it could be provided upon request. If not -- then tough luck.

Comment: Ignoring white space and punctuation is handled directly by the FULL TEXT index feature in MySQL. All you have to do is define the targeted text column(s) as a an index.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example and a link to using MySQL FULLTEXT indexing.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of sorting results using PHP, with some performance/memory usage tests:

```
// get current time and memory usage
$startTime = microtime(true);
$startMemory = memory_get_usage();

// get all rows
$queryRef = mysql_query('select id, name from product', $dbConnection);
$rows = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($queryRef, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
  $rows[] = $row;
}

// sort rows
function myCmp($a, $b)
{
  $aName = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/', '', strtolower($a['name']));
  $bName = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/', '', strtolower($b['name']));

  return strcmp($aName, $bName);
}
usort($rows, 'myCmp');

// output time and memory usage statistics
$endTime = microtime(true);
$endMemory = memory_get_usage();
var_dump(array(
  'count' => count($rows),
  'time' => round($endTime - $startTime, 3) . ' seconds',
  'memory' => (($endMemory - $startMemory) / 1024 / 1204) . 'MB'
));

// output result
var_dump($rows);
```

In my testing, with a small amount of data, that only takes a few milliseconds and a  few hundred killobytes of RAM. With a large amount of data it becomes far too slow and uses too much memory.

If it's too slow or memory intensive, you need to look into other more complicated options as @MihaiStancu suggests.

Another option is duplicate data. Perhaps instead of just a "name" column, you could have a "name_for_sorting" column that contains the name already in lowercase and with punctuation/whitespace/etc removed.

Comment: Just a sidenote: your `myCmp()` function is comparing stripped strings  and you're feeding it entire arrays. Using `preg_replace` and `strcmp` on arrays would yield an error.

Comment: Even if you would feed `myCmp()` with `$row['name']`, you will still be comparing full length (stripped) article titles. So if there are multiple words in the titles you will only be comparing the strict equality of stripped titles -- meaning you're just stripping punctuation and the comparing stuff. You could easily do this much faster and more scalable directly from MySQL either by using MySQL level RegEx to strip the punctuation or -- better -- using the MySQL FULL TEXT search index i've mentioned which already does that.

Comment: Also we are talking about "searching" not "sorting". So you should be comparing each `$row['name']` to a `$_GET['q']` or something like that using `array_filter` instead of `usort` (because we don't need to sort anything).